# How do I fix the sound issues in the Sonic series iOS games?

Tags: ios, sonic-the-hedgehog, sonic-the-hedgehog-2, sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-1

Been having this issue for a bit. Basically the sound stops playing in [Sonic 1](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog/id316025912?mt=8), [Sonic 2](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog-2/id347411942?mt=8) and [Sonic 4 episode one](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-i/id392788790?mt=8). The first time it happened I just redownloaded the games and then it was fine but now it has happened again and I don't know why.

I am on a 4s with the most recent version of iOS (version 5.0.1). I was just wondering if anyone else is having this issue and whether they know how to fix it.

I did contact Sega and all they had to say was that there are trying to update for iOS 5 as fast as they can.

Comment: Hello Ley and welcome to gaming! I don't own any iOS devices, but even if I did I'm not sure I would understand which game you are having an issue with (is it some sort of Sonic compilation game? Maybe you can supply a link to the app store to make this clearer?) . Also, I would personally specify the exact iOS version you have, as while it might be "most recent" now, that may not hold in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it best I could. I could only post two links.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to improve your question. I hope someone will be able to provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of contacting the developer - [Sega Mobile Games](https://help.sega.net/hc/en-us) -  about this issue. They report that they haven't had any other complaints about the sound issue prior to my report, and consider it an isolated problem.

Here is the relevant excerpt from their response:

> ...I am unfamiliar with the specifics of that potential bug, but am glad to hear that reinstalling seems to have resolved it for the person on that website. Given how long ago that was mentioned, and that I have not seen any reports of the issue, it was likely either an isolated problem or long-since fixed. Hope that helps!

Since you reported this a few years ago on your iPhone 4S with iOS version 5.0.1, If this issue is still occurring for you, I would recommend updating both your phone OS version and the apps themselves:

- [The most recent iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204204) version (as of writing) is 8.0.4.
- [Sonic the Hedgehog](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog/id316025912?mt=8) is now on version 2.8.0 as of Apr 29, 2015
- [Sonic the Hedgehog 2](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog-2/id347411942?mt=8) is now on version 3.1.4 as of Apr 29, 2015
- [Sonic the Hedgehog 4: Episode 1](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-i/id392788790?mt=8) is on version 1.4 as of Aug 15, 2012

If the issue is still occurring after updating, please raise a ticket with [Sega Mobile Games Support](https://help.sega.net/hc/en-us/requests/new). Link them back to this question to help provide context.

Comment: gonna update this for iOS as of Apr 16, 2019;  
iOS is 12.2.  
Sonic the Hedgehog is at 3.2.5
Sonic the Hedgehog 2 is at 4.2.2.  
Sonic the Hedgehog 4: Episode 1 is at 1.5.
StH 4: Episode 2 was released, and is at 3.0.2.